# Сравнение массивов с++

Tags: c++, массивы, сравнение, динамические-массивы

На форуме не нашел подобного вопроса.
Нужно сравнить два массива символов и определить является ли одна строка перестановкой другой.
Вот как я это вижу: два массива, в цикле сравниваем первый элемент с первой таблицы со всеми элементами со второй, потом второй,...,n.
Проблема в том, что я не знаю как это описать. Пробовал через if, но не получается.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int _size = 10;

int main(){    
    char *tab = new char [_size];
    cin >> tab;

    char *tab1 = new char [_size];
    cin >> tab1;
    cout << tab1 << endl;
    cout << tab << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j<_size; j++)
            if(tab[i] == tab1[j]) 
}
```

Comment: Почему массивы распределяются динамически?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

полным перебором будет слишком не эффективно - тупо отсортируйте оба массива и сравните на равенство каждого символа одново массива с другим, одним циклом.
например так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

bool isPermutation(char* str1, char* str2, int size)
{
    std::sort(str1, str1 + size);
    std::sort(str2, str2 + size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (str1[i] != str2[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}


int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    char* str1 = new char[size];
    char* str2 = new char[size];
    std::cin >> str1 >> str2;
    std::cout << isPermutation(str1, str2, 10);
    delete[] str1;
    delete[] str2;
    return 0;
}
```

и не забывайте освобождать динамически выделенную память

Comment: Спасибо, буду стараться не забывать.

Answer (score 2):

По идее тебе нужно всего то проверить что кол-во 1 символа в строке 1 равно кол-ву в строке 2.
Т.к. символ это char - тоесть 1 byte (0..255), то проще будет создать массив и инициализировать его нулями

```
int* charsInStr1 = new int[256];
int* charsInStr2 = new int[256];
```

Далее пройтись по массивам:

```
for(int i = 0; i < str1Size; i++)
   charsInStr1[(byte)str1[i]]++;
```

А после сравнить 2 массива charsInStr1 и charsInStr2. 
Сложность будет O(4*n).

Comment: См. мое второе решение :) Можно просто вносить с плюсом из одного массива, и с минусом - из второго. Но если ТС предпочитает помучиться, то кто ж ему судья? :)

Answer (score 0):

Предпочитаю решать в общем случае...

А в общем случае лучше уж отсортировать и сравнивать. Тогда получим `O(n*log n)`, а не `O(n^2)`. При определенных данных, допускающих более быструю сортировку (как, например, `char`) - и того быстрее, за `O(n)` - см. второй вариант...

Да и потом, вы должны как минимум во втором массиве помечать, что этот элемент уже участвовал в проверке - иначе {1,1,2} и {1,2,2,} у вас будут одинаковы.

Что-то типа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned int N;
    cout << "Input size: ";
    cin >> N;

    int * s = new int[N];
    int * t = new int[N];

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Input s["<<(i+1)<<"]: ";
        cin >> s[i];
    }
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Input t["<<(i+1)<<"]: ";
        cin >> t[i];
    }

    sort(s,s+N);
    sort(t,t+N);
    cout << "s is " << (equal(s,s+N,t) ? "" : "not ")
         << "equal to t\n";

    delete[]s;
    delete[]t;
}
```

Можно даже - если использовать вектора - заменить `equal` на просто `==`.

Если числа небольшие - а символы это и есть числа до 255... - вот метод проверки `O(n)` - складываем в массив количества и смотрим, что получается.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned int N;
    cout << "Input max value (no more than 100): ";
    cin >> N;

    int * s = new int[N+1];

    memset(s,0,sizeof(int)*(N+1));

    cout << "Input first array (-1 to stop): ";
    for(;;)
    {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        if (x < 0) break;
        if (x > N)
        {
            cout << "Wrong value, ignored...\n";
            continue;
        }
        s[x]++;
    }

    cout << "Input second array (-1 to stop): ";
    for(;;)
    {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        if (x < 0) break;
        if (x > N)
        {
            cout << "Wrong value, ignored...\n";
            continue;
        }
        s[x]--;
    }

    bool equ = true;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        if (s[i])
        {
            equ = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "s is " << (equ ? "" : "not ")
         << "equal to t\n";

}
```

Comment: а память не хотите освободить ?

Comment: @ampawd А надо? у меня программа на этом заканчивается, память освободится и сама... Ну ладно, только для вас :)

Answer (score 0):

Задание легко выполнить, если разрешается использовать стандартные контейнеры. Вы можете занести все символы каждой их строк в стандартный контейнер `std::map`, а затем сравнить эти контейнеры.

При этом сами исходные строки не изменяются.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    char s1[N];
    char s2[N];

    std::cout << "Enter the first string: ";
    std::cin.getline( s1, sizeof( s1 ) );

    std::cout << "Enter the second string: ";
    std::cin.getline( s2, sizeof( s2 ) );

    bool permutation = std::strlen( s1 ) == std::strlen( s2 );  

    if ( permutation )
    {
        std::map<char, size_t> m1;
        std::map<char, size_t> m2;

        for ( const char *p = s1; *p; ++p ) ++m1[*p];
        for ( const char *p = s2; *p; ++p ) ++m2[*p];

        permutation = m1 == m2;
    }

    if( permutation ) std::cout << "The strings represent themselves a permutation";
    else std::cout << "The strings do not represent themselves a permutation";

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

я так понял что, одна строка может имеет тот же набор символов что и другая, только одна перетасована, а может и не иметь. Вот это нужно и выявить.

Следовательно:

1) сравнить размер строк, если они различены, то уже наборы разные, а если равны то переходим к пункту два.

2)  тут может быть ситуация такая, что все символы есть НО ИХ КОЛИЧЕСТВО РАЗНОЕ, по этому
тут главное подсчитать количество одного символа в одной строке и в другой, а далее сравнить эти количества и так со всеми уникальными символами из одной любой строки.

Сделать это можно, допустив неиспользуемый символ к примеру пробел, его мы считать не будем, зачем он нужен... Пробелом мы будем удалять подсчитанный символ из строки.

НО можно и просто удалять символ по образцу из строки урезая ее.

-Перебираем только одну любую строку в качестве образца, НО также ее и анализируем как и вторую строку, чтоб она сокращалась как и вторая, для уменьшения уникальных образцов, чтоб повторных образцов не_было.

-берем символ и помещаем в переменную образец.

-счетчик один, счетчик второй для второй строки, которые будем сравнивать.

-берем образец и сравниваем с символами в строке, и как только находим его то удаляем из строки и увеличиваем счетчик один, строки первой.

- идем дальше и как только достигли дна, переходим к счетчику два и повторяем операцию со строкой два.
- идем дальше и как только достигнули дна то сравниваем счетчики, если они одинаковые то берем образец два, иначе наборы символов в строках разные, стоп проверка.
- повторяем выше изложенное со всеми образцами символов и з постепенно уменьшающейся строки.

-образец можно брать уже из строки в которой удалены символы, а увеличение счетчиков делать при одновременном сравнении образца с разными строками.

- код писать не буду, потому как и так все ясно, а когда ясно, что должно происходить то и код сам проявляется...))

В общем тут главное подсчет символов одного типа в одной строке и в другой, затем сравнение и дальше в перед.